# Не получается сделать калькулятор на js

Tags: javascript, html

Решил сделать по гайдам простой калькулятор, но в место результата получаю NaN.

```js
function plus() {

  var num1, num2, result;
  num1 = document.getElementById('n1').value;
  num1 = parseInt(num1);

  num2 = document.getElementById('n2').value;
  num2 = Number(num2);

  result = num1 + num2;
  document.getElementById('out').innerHTML = result;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>js</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>КАЛкулятор</h1>
  <div class="NumAll">
    <p class="Num1" id="n1">
      <input type="text">
    </p>
    <p class="Num2" id="n2">
      <input type="text">
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="btn">
    <button>Вычесть</button>
    <button onclick="plus()">Сложить</button>
    <button>Умножить</button>
    <button>Делить</button>
  </div>
  <p class="Res" id="out">Результат</p>
  <script src="/js/script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Идентификаторы `id="n1"` и `id="n2"` вы должны присвоить полям для ввода (`<input type="text" id="n1">` к примеру)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ !